# Carbon elements missing from catalogue

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm unable to see carbon elements from the polymer website https://elements.polymer-project.org/.

Did they move the site after google I/O 2016? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-05-19-Polymer-IO-2016

> carbon elements become app elements

which can be found at https://elements.polymer-project.org/